# Prove set intersection is null

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The questions asked me to prove this.

I have no idea what I'm doing and I do not have the book. Prove If $A$ is a subset of $B$, and $B\cap C=\emptyset$, then $A\cap C=\emptyset$.

Comment: Hint: Think of A as being "inside" B, since A is a subset of B. Looking at B's intersection with C, what can you conclude about A's intersection with C?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $
A\cap C\neq \emptyset
$. Then there is $x\in A$, suc as $x\in C$. As $A\subset B$, $x\in B $ (and $x\in C$). So $B\cap C\neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap C\subseteq B\cap C=\emptyset$ implies $A\cap C=\emptyset$ because the only subset of the empty set is the empty set itself.